# Why is function composition from left to right 11x to 19x faster than right to left?

Tags: performance, f#

I encountered this phenomenon when writing my poor man's version of FParsec. Consider:

```
let add x = x+1
let fromLeft  = add>>add>>add>>add>>add>>add>>add>>add>>add>>add
let fromRight = add<<add<<add<<add<<add<<add<<add<<add<<add<<add
let imperative x =
    let mutable result = x
    for i = 0 to 9 do
        result <- add result
    result
```

And test the performance of all three functions:

```
let runs = 10000000
printf "From left\n"
time(fun()->fromLeft 0) runs
printf "\nFrom right\n"
time(fun()->fromRight 0) runs
printf "\nImperative\n"
time(fun()->imperative 0) runs
```

The results are:
59ms for `fromLeft`, 658 ms for `fromRight` 
and 26 ms for `Imperative`.

The test is done in Release mode and outside of VS. The results are stable and do not depend on the order in which I test the functions. The factor by which the performance of the two compositions differs is 11x or 19x if the `Imperative` run time is taken to be the overhead of the `add` function itself and is subtracted from both results.

Does anyone know the reason for such a discrepancy?

My `time` combinator is

```
let inline time func n =
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    printfn "Starting"
    let stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    for i = 0 to n-1 do func() |> ignore
    stopwatch.Stop()
    printfn "Took %A ms" stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Sadly the compiler definitions of `<<` and `>>` are of no help. https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs

Comment: What does [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) say?

Comment: It seems that the compiler is not doing some optimization that it could be doing. A great chance for submitting a pull request http://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very rough answer would be that the compiler is in-lining the functions in `fromLeft`, but for some reason isn't doing the same optimization for `fromRight`.  It is possible to force the associativity by fully parenthesizing the composition like this:

```
let fromLeft  = add>>(add>>(add>>(add>>(add>>(add>>(add>>(add>>(add>>add))))))))
let fromRight = ((((((((add<<add)<<add)<<add)<<add)<<add)<<add)<<add)<<add)<<add
```

resulting in:

```
From left
Starting
Took 645.648 ms

From right
Starting
Took 625.058 ms

Imperative
Starting
Took 23.0332 ms
```

Reversing the parenthesization like this:

```
let fromLeft = ((((((((add>>add)>>add)>>add)>>add)>>add)>>add)>>add)>>add)>>add
let fromRight  = add<<(add<<(add<<(add<<(add<<(add<<(add<<(add<<(add<<add))))))))
```

results in:

```
From left
Starting
Took 86.3503 ms

From right
Starting
Took 75.6358 ms

Imperative
Starting
Took 33.7193 ms
```

So this just looks like an optimization which is missing from the compiler.

Comment: This is very unfortunate. While this is exactly the sort of thing I pay close attention to when writing C++ (and that pedantry is why I love C++), this is also exactly the sort of thing I write F# to _avoid_ thinking about... Now it's always going to be in the back of my mind to avoid `<<` and possibly `<|` for performance reasons.

Comment: @ildjarn The F# compiler now takes pull requests ;-)

Comment: @mydogisbox Thanks! Apparently it's left- or right- associativity that matters for performance. Would any of you gents consider making a pull request? I've just started to learn F# and that's not somebody you'd want to write the compiler!

Comment: @Arbil They review your PR, so if you're interested don't let that stop you.